# How to clone SQL table with index

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with a mysql table which I'd like to clone and give another name. When I try the

> CREATE TABLE data1 AS SELECT * FROM data;

It gets stuck in execution, and never actually do anything, and I have to abort.

The thing is that my table "data" has some extra commands in the sql source like

> CREATE INDEX keywords ON data (keywords);

It has a few of these, and I suspect that this is what's causing the issue, since I have been able to clone other tables without these extra commmands. I'm new in sql, so I have no idea how to overcome this problem. Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 0):

Use is `create table like` syntax. to create a table with the same structure and after this you can copy the data.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html

a second solution is to use `mysqldump` to extract the table structur including the data, rename the table in dump file and Reimport the it.

Comment: Okay, I can use the like syntax, and it creates the table, however doesn't import data. How do I copy the data? extracting it from the .dump file seems a little cumbersome..

Comment: @1233023 insert into  data1 
(SELECT * FROM data  );

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Here it gets stuck in execution and I have to abort

Comment: @1233023 Than try the dump

Answer (score 0):

-- To copy table with constraints

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE old_table_name;
```

-- To copy without constraints

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
(SELECT * FROM old_table_name WHERE 0);
```

[source](http://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/mysql/how-to-copy-table-with-constraints-in-mysql)